# how can use two where in one column with mysql join query?

Tags: mysql, sql

im using mysql for **database** project , i have one **mysql** table taxonomy .

i needed post_id with condition tax_id = 1 and tax_id = 2 in mysql , also if i want **usable for join** sql .

example :

```
post_id | tax_id
------- | ------
  1     |   1
  1     |   2
  2     |   1
  2     |   3
```

i want postid equal with condation taxid equal 1 and 2

for example my using this sql but not working :

```
SELECT * FROM `term_relationships` WHERE tax_id = 9 AND tax_id = 1120 ;
```

Comment: @Barmar this qustion not dublicated . plz delet this mark form this question .

Comment: What's the difference between your question and the one I linked to?

Comment: @Barmar this question find tax_id To assume 2 and 4 and must find 1 post_id but that qustion just find two id not grouped post_id . pay attention .

Comment: It's the same thing. That question looks for the Score that has both id=2 and id=4. Your question is to find the post ID that has both tax_id=1 and tax_id=2.

Comment: @Barmar  no no  . This is not only . you must In addition, pick a post .

Comment: for example you find in tax 4 and 2 post_id 1 . this post_id is dublicated . you must using onec .

Comment: I've reopened the question. Please edit it to clarify what you really want.

Comment: I don't understand. There is no tax 4 in the sample data.

Comment: thank you . Please enter values in a table top and see result with query which I confirmed .

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying there. Your question is poorly written. The example table has `tax_id`, but your query has `term_taxonomy_id`. The example table has `tax_id = 1, 2, 3`, but the query has `9` and `1120`. And you never show what you want the result to be like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select post_id
from term_relationships
group by post_id
having count(case when term_taxonomy_id in (9, 1120) then 1 end) = 2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ea04/3)

Comment: @Barmar plz you using this sql .

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

You can use [`IN`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `term_relationships` WHERE term_taxonomy_id in (9,1120);
```

Comment: This will return the posts that have either of the taxonomy IDs. He only wants posts that have *both*.